# Merge DataRow to SQL Server database table

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, datagridview

In my SQL Server 2008 R2 database, I have an existing table `[dbo].[abc].[MyTable]`. Now I want to read the rows from my DataGridView and merge them into `MyTable`.

Suppose I use a stored procedure.

I have no idea for looping through and merging rows.

Thanks for help.

```
private void saveRecords(DataGridView dgv)
{
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
            // merge it to table in database.
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a command builder, take a look at [this SqlCommandBuilder example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommandbuilder) .

Comment: Do I have to create a datatable first? Because I want to merge rather than purely inserting or updating table. The records maybe already exist in the table. Maybe not then you have to insert.

Comment: Yes, you have to load the database table into a data table first ... See the example on the link

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLBulkCopy to pull all the data from your grid into a table on your DB, and then simply use SQL to merge the data togehter (assuming they have some kind of related data)

This link will provide how to do Bulk copies:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server

Comment: I need merge command for dealing with DataRow. Merge command is a new command in Sql Server 2008 r2.

Comment: If you bulk copy to a table first, you would be just going against a regular table, it wouldn't be a dataRow anymore.

Comment: Does bulk copy overwrite the existing rows?